# python logging logger with only filehandler is writing to both file and stdout/err

Tags: python, logging

I have a logger that only has a file handlers, which works properly. However for some reason it will also always output to stdout/err too.

```
In [10]: import logging

In [11]: logger = logging.getLogger('custom_logger')

In [12]: logger.handlers
Out[12]: [<FileHandler /tmp/log_2023-06-29_15-29-25.log (NOTSET)>]

In [13]: logger.info('test')
INFO:custom_logger:test   <<< This shouldn't happen!
```

The FileHandler is a simple handler with a custom formatter (json formatter), but the same issue also happens when using no formatter (default formatter): the logs get written to both the File and the standard (error) output / terminal.

using `.clear()` on the handlers before adding the File handler didn't help. And as you can see in `.handlers` only the FileHandler is listed. What could be happening here? (The example I provided is with ipython, but it is not a matter of ipython either as the same issue happens everywhere: with python3 direct use, when running tests etc...)

Am I missing something obvious? `python3.10.6`

EDIT:

Even when clearing all handlers, it will still log to stdout/err (but not to file)

```
In [3]: logger.handlers.clear()

In [4]: logger.info('test')
INFO:custom_logger:test
```

instead of not logging at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find the source of the issue. There are other loggers in other places of the code so maybe they interact in a bad way somehow.

I found the following workaround:

```
logger.propagate = False
logger.info('test')  <<< doesn't display anything anymore
```

It seems that it always ends up defaulting to an other logger even though the level is properly set for the logger (and the FileHandler). I also tried changing the log level or root logger (used for: `logger.root`, `logger.manager.root` and `logger.parent`) but this did not work.